# Grrovy how to get directory files by name only without the path I have the following code I need to get the numbers only

Tags: groovy

Grrovy how to get directory files by name only without the path I have the following code  I need to get the numbers only

```
'''
import groovy.io.FileType
def cnode= []

def dir = new File("/var/jenkins_home/files/")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
cnode << file
}

cnode.each {
cnode = it
  println cnode
}
```

'''

Comment: Are you looking for `file.name`? If not, you might want to clarify the question with [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@siking's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72036160/grrovy-how-to-get-directory-files-by-name-only-without-the-path-i-have-the-follo/72042435#comment127285413_72036160): I added `.name`, and I got the name instead of the path.

```
1
2
3
4
5
Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    '''
    import groovy.io.FileType
    def cnode = []
    def dir = new File("/var/jenkins_home/files/")
    dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file -> cnode << file.name }
    cnode.each {
      cnode = it
      println cnode
    }
'''
```